# PostgreSQL Big Query optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-9.1, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

```
select aa.id as attendance_approvals_id, al.id, al.check_in_time, al.check_out_time, 
    al.check_in_selfie, al.check_out_selfie, al.check_in_approval, al.check_out_approval, 
    al.check_in_distance_variation, al.check_out_distance_variation, al.updated_at,  
    ar.attendance_reason, a.start_date, a.end_date, e.first_name as employee_name,e.profile_picture, 
    aa.action as action, aa.updated_at, b.branch_name, e.emp_id, e.id as employee_id 
        from attendances a
        inner join attendance_logs al on a.id = al.attendance_id 
        and a.delete_flag = 0 and a.start_date between '2018-11-21' and '2018-11-28'
        inner join attendance_approvals aa on aa.attendance_log_id = al.id 
        and aa.approval_flag = 0 and aa.active_flag = 1
        inner join attendance_reasons ar on ar.id = al.reason_id 
        inner join employees e on e.id = a.employee_id and e.manager_id = 16266
        inner join branches b on b.id = e.branch_id
        inner join employee_shift_mappings esm on esm.emp_id = e.id and esm.shift_date = a.start_date
    group by aa.id, al.id, al.check_in_time, al.check_out_time, al.check_in_selfie, 
        al.check_out_selfie, al.check_in_approval, 
        al.check_out_approval, al.check_in_distance_variation, al.check_out_distance_variation, 
        al.updated_at,  ar.attendance_reason, 
        a.start_date, a.end_date, e.first_name, e.profile_picture, aa.action, aa.updated_at, 
        b.branch_name,e.emp_id, e.id 
        order by aa.id desc
```

How to Optimize this query, this will take more than 35sec for execution.

- attendances table has **7 700 000**  records.
- attendance_logs table has **6 400 000** records.
- attendance_approvals table has **3 900 000**  records.
- attendance_reasons table has **570** records.
- employees  table has **60 000** records.
- employee_shift_mappings  table has **1 300 000** records.

[Please find my Query Plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/70Nv)

```
"Group  (cost=94304.75..94304.77 rows=1 width=365) (actual time=23724.836..23724.859 rows=43 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: aa.id, al.id, ar.attendance_reason, a.start_date, a.end_date, b.branch_name, e.id"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=94304.75..94304.76 rows=1 width=365) (actual time=23724.832..23724.839 rows=43 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: aa.id DESC, al.id, ar.attendance_reason, a.start_date, a.end_date, b.branch_name, e.id"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 47kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.15..94304.74 rows=1 width=365) (actual time=258.375..23724.602 rows=43 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.86..94297.49 rows=1 width=350) (actual time=258.364..23724.098 rows=43 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: (al.reason_id = ar.id)"
"                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 24467"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.86..94277.15 rows=1 width=338) (actual time=258.344..23719.534 rows=43 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.42..5220.10 rows=2 width=322) (actual time=0.615..26.969 rows=344 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..5204.67 rows=2 width=127) (actual time=0.600..22.920 rows=394 loops=1)"
"                                      Join Filter: (e.id = esm.emp_id)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..5116.43 rows=11 width=131) (actual time=0.573..17.221 rows=394 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on employees e  (cost=0.00..4437.62 rows=79 width=111) (actual time=0.334..15.277 rows=84 loops=1)"
"                                                  Filter: (manager_id = 16266)"
"                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 59110"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using uk_attendance_status on attendances a  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.008..0.017 rows=5 loops=84)"
"                                                  Index Cond: ((employee_id = e.id) AND (start_date >= '2018-11-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (start_date <= '2018-11-28 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (delete_flag = 0))"
"                                      ->  Index Only Scan using idx_shift_mapping on employee_shift_mappings esm  (cost=0.43..8.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=394)"
"                                            Index Cond: ((emp_id = a.employee_id) AND (shift_date = a.start_date))"
"                                            Heap Fetches: 394"
"                                ->  Index Scan using index_attendance_logs on attendance_logs al  (cost=0.43..7.71 rows=1 width=203) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=394)"
"                                      Index Cond: (attendance_id = a.id)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using index_attendance_approvals on attendance_approvals aa  (cost=0.43..44528.51 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=68.758..68.872 rows=0 loops=344)"
"                                Index Cond: ((attendance_log_id = al.id) AND (active_flag = 1))"
"                                Filter: (approval_flag = 0)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on attendance_reasons ar  (cost=0.00..12.93 rows=593 width=20) (actual time=0.004..0.055 rows=570 loops=43)"
"              ->  Index Scan using branches_pkey on branches b  (cost=0.29..7.24 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=43)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = e.branch_id)"
"Planning time: 3.099 ms"
"Execution time: 23725.179 ms"
```

Comment: Why the huge `group by` if you are not doing any aggregation? It seems to include the primary key columns of all tables involved so it won't actually remove any duplicates

Comment: One simple performance improvement is to ditch the unsupported Version 9.1 and upgrade to 11

Comment: Do things improve if you raise `default_statistics_target` and then `ANALYZE attendances`?

Comment: In addition, I would create an index `ON attendances (employee_id, start_date) WHERE delete_flag = 0`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Attendances table already have indexed by 'employee_id, start_date'

Comment: I see. Your main problem is the bad estimate in the index scan on this table - 1 instead if 5.If you can improve that (maybe with better statistics), performance will improve.

Comment: As a crude measure, you can try setting `enable_nestloop = off` for this query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe _enable_nestloop = off_ is working and execution time reduces to 4 sec.

Comment: Handle with care.